# How to change editor background color in vscode using editor.tokenColorCustomizations instead of workbench

Tags: visual-studio-code

I currently use 
 `{ "workbench.colorCustomizations": { "editor.background": "#2B1B17" } }`
to change background colour of themes in visual studio code but as you know using workbench settings `workbench.colorCustomizations` I have to create a new `.vscode/settings.json` for each new project I start.
I want to do it globally!.
I wonder if is there a way to use global **User settings.json** to change the background colour of the theme, something like the one I use to change the comment's colour:  `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {"comments": "#82CAFF"}`

Thank You

Answer (score 13):

Writing:

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "editor.background": "#2B1B17"
    }
}
```

In your user settings.json should work.

You can find this file in `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` if you use vscode on Linux.